# how to fetch a particular value from realtime database in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch only the temp value from the database as shown below

```
1234567789
    bpm: 
       65
    temp: 
       21

    fetchdata() async{
        final dbref= FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
         dbref.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) => {
          print(snap.value),
          snap.value.forEach((key,values){
            print(values['temp']);
          })
    
         });
      }
```

this is the function i am using where to put child parameter to fetch data from the particular child that is 1234567789 here
I am getting the output as

```
{12345666789: {temp: 36, bpm: 65}, 1234567789: {temp: 21, bpm: 65}
```

I only want to get value 36 here.How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the ['cloud firestore'](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-installing-tab-) package.
Here is some of my code.
Hope it helps!

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

DocumentReference user = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userID);

user.get().then((documentSnapshot) {
      if(documentSnapshot.exists){
        User user1= new User();
        user1.userID = userID;
        user1.userName = documentSnapshot.data['name'].toString();
        user1.profileIcon = documentSnapshot.data['profileIcon'].toString();
        user1.profileColor = documentSnapshot.data['profileColor'].toString();
        return user1;
      }else{
        return null;
      }
});
```